# React native Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

i am currently working a small app i have just started working on and i keep getting this error:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in RNCViewPager (at ViewPager.js:150)
    in ViewPager (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at react-native-scrollable-tab-view/index.js:253)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
```

I am using import ScrollableTabView, { DefaultTabBar } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view'; and i guess this is where the error is getting from, i have searched on stackoverflow and found that i have to install @react-native-community/viewpager which i did, but still getting the same error in the Android emulator (the Ios emulator works)

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text
} from 'react-native';

import ScrollableTabView, { DefaultTabBar } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
//import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager'
export default () => {
  return <ScrollableTabView
    style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
    initialPage={1}
    renderTabBar={() => <DefaultTabBar />}
  >
    <Text tabLabel='Tab #1'>

    </Text>
    <Text tabLabel='Tab #2'>favorite</Text>
    <Text tabLabel='Tab #3'>project</Text>
  </ScrollableTabView>;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Have you run `cd ios && pod install` command after installing libraries ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533273/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncviewpager-was-not-found-in-the)

Answer (score 16):

if you use yarn

> yarn add react-native-pager-view

if not, then

> npm i react-native-pager-view

then you have to do

> pod install

> yarn ios or npx react-native run-ios

Comment: Just for some references, since this is the most voted answer now, I tried it but it didn't work for me. I am doing an expo for android now. I all of sudden remember that I likely need to rebuild the project since this is react native package but not included in expo. I also reinstall the app on my Android device after rebuilding. It then starts to work. Hopefully, this can help. So I eventually gave this a vote.

Answer (score 11):

Install the below NPM library

```
npm i react-native-pager-view
```

Because, "@react-native-community/viewpager" is Deprecated.

Comment: for me, I had to recompile the project after adding this library as I started getting an error

Answer (score 6):

Install the following package

```
npm i react-native-pager-view
```

After that open the `ios` folder in the terminal and run `pod install`. After the installation restart your project with `npx react-native start`.

Answer (score 5):

Please run the following command in your terminal

```
=> npm i @react-native-community/viewpager
```

Comment: This was answered in:
https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/1050#issuecomment-551376517

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/viewpager                        This package has been deprecated

Author message:
This library is no longer supported. Please use react-native-pager-view instead

Comment: This is no longer valid. npm i react-native-pager-view
cd ios
pod install

Answer (score 5):

Kindly install this package first

```
npm i react-native-pager-view
```

You need to make sure of your node & npm version. In my case, I used node v.16.13.0 (npm v.8.1.0). If npm didn't work, try using yarn

```
yarn add react-native-pager-view
```

after that. `cd ios && pod install`

Then you need to rebuild the app on android. If the issue still exists, then try deleting node_modules & pods, then reinstall them again.

Comment: This one fixed my issue as of 2023. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only if other answers didn't work for you, as they didn't work for me, try downgrading 'react-native-tab-view'

```
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
```

or

```
npm i react-native-tab-view@^2.16.0
```

then restart your project.

Comment: Is this bc the react-native-pager-view is a dependency of react-native-tab-view? By that logic, do you recommend I downgrade all the packages that use it?