# REACT-NATIVE Unimplemented component : <RNCViewPager>

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use [react-native-tab-view](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator) in my app, made with react-native.
It launches successfully, but on the emulator's screen appears following messages:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pVVS.png)

Here's me code:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'

import type { FC } from 'react'

import { HomeScreen, ProfileScreen } from '~screens'
import { TCommonRoutes } from '~types'

export const CommonRoutes: FC = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<TCommonRoutes>()
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<TCommonRoutes>()

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

What I've already done:

1. yarn add @react-navigation/material-top-tabs react-native-tab-view
2. yarn add react-native-pager-view
3. cd ios && pod install

What I've already watched:

1. [React native Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953648/react-native-invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncviewpager-was-not)
2. [Android: Invariant Violation requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was ton found in the UIManager](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/1050)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this dependencies before using react-native-tab-view
Run the following commands

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

If you are using Expo run

```
expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

If you have bare react native project run

```
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you need to install the pods
For iOS run from Macbook Only

```
npx pod-install ios
```

For Android you need to do this extra step
Edit `MainActivity.java` file which is located in `android/app/src/main/java/<your package name>/MainActivity.java`.
Add the following code to the body of MainActivity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(null);
}
```

and make sure to add an import statement at the top of this file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```