# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-tab-view, react-native-pager-view

Trying to integrate react-native into my existing iOS application. Here are the contents of my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "MyReactNativeApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "yarn react-native start"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
        "axios": "^1.3.3",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "^0.71.3",
        "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.4",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
    }
}
```

I am able to build and run the application with all these libraries installed. When I am using tab view (which is dependent on react-native-pager-view), I get the following error:

Complete error:

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not
> found in the UIManager.
>
> This error is located at: in RNCViewPager (created by PagerView) in
> PagerView (created by AnimatedComponent) in AnimatedComponent in
> AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PagerViewAdapter) in
> PagerViewAdapter (created by TabView) in RCTView (created by View) in
> View (created by TabView) in TabView (created by App) in Provider
> (created by App) in App in RCTView (created by View) in View (created
> by AppContainer) in RCTView (created by View) in View (created by
> AppContainer) in AppContainer in MyReactNativeApp(RootComponent), js
> engine: hermes

I've installed react-native-tab-view and react-native-pager-view and since i am using react-native 0.71.3, I do not need to link them manually.

Please help with this if any idea.

tried installing react-native-tab-view and react-native-pager-view.
Also installed @react-native-community/viewpager (although deprecated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that when i hit pod install, react-native-pager-view was not being installed.
Here's what I found out:

I was using use_react_native! in my podfile.
But since react-native-pager-view uses native modules (UIPageViewController in swift), you need to make sure that you enable native modules like this in your podfile:

```
config = use_native_modules!

# Flags change depending on the env values.
flags = get_default_flags()
use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath],
:hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
:fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
:app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
)
```

This worked for me.